# Midpoint of a line segment passing through two points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, locus, geometric-transformation

> Let $C_1$ be a circle defined with $X(-2,7)$ and $Y(2,-5)$ as the endpoints of the diameter of the circle.
> Let $C_2$ be a circle defined with $Y(2,-5)$ and $Z(4,-11)$ as the endpoints of the diameter of the circle.

> Let $A = C_1 \cup C_2 - Y$

> Let $B$ be the set of all midpoints of the set of all straight line segments joining two distinct points in $A$ and passing through the point $Y$. Find $B$.

---

**My attempt:**

Since $XYZ$ are collinear $C_1$ and $C_2$ meet at a single point: $Y$. I can easily find the set of all midpoints of the line segments joining a point (say $T$) in $C_1$ and $Y$. Let $M(x,y)$ be the midpoint of $TY$ and $N(0,1)$ be the center of $C_1$. Notice that $MN$ is perpendicular to to $MY$. Therefore we can build the equation $\dfrac{y-1}{x-0}*\dfrac{y+5}{x-2}=-1$ i.e product of their slopes equal -1. Similarly, the set of all midpoints of the line segments joining a point (say $U$) in $C_2$ and $Y$ can be found.
The issue now is, I don't know how to use this information to compute the required locus $B$. I don't even know if this information is useful.

Comment: The diameter of the solution circle should be $YW$, where $W$ is the midpoint of $XZ$. Then the equation will be $(x-x(W))(x-x(Y))+(y-y(W))(y-y(Y))=0.$

Comment: Uhm can u provide a proof please?

Comment: $W, Y$ certainly is in $B$ and are extremal. Do you need a proof that it's a circle?

Comment: Yeah I can visualise why W is in B. The line segment XZ passes through Y and midpoint is W. I can't seem to prove why Y must be in B. And if it is why is the locus B defined by the circle YW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locus of points dividing segments joining points of $S_1$ with points of $S_2$ in ratio $\lambda : (1-\lambda)$ is given by $$\lambda S_1 + (1-\lambda) S_2=0$$

$(2,-5)$ should lie on this locus, which it clearly does. For midpoints, put $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. The coefficient of $x^2$ and $y^2$ will turn out to be same; this locus is a circle.

Given $$S_1 : (x-2)(x+2) + (y+5)(y-7)=0$$
$$S_2 : (x-2)(x-4) + (y+5)(y+11)=0$$

Required locus is $$S : (x-2)(x-1) + (y+5)(y+2)=0$$

with center at $$\Big(\dfrac{2+1}{2},\dfrac{-5-2}{2}\Big)=\Big(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{-7}{2}\Big)$$

Comment: OK just one qstn. pls point out the line segment causing Y to be part of the locus B. bcuz i cant seem to find such a line segment that joins two distinct points in A and whose midpoint is Y. pls describe such a line segment. thank you.

Comment: The way $A$ has been defined, it excludes $Y$. But there is no reason to define such $A$. The line segment of zero length joining $Y$ of $S_1$ to $Y$ of $S_2$ also satisfies this property, that its midpoint is $Y$. This line segment consists of single point $Y$, which the definition of $A$ excludes, to consider only line segments of non-zero length. Have you come across similar concept of considering a single point as a circle of zero radius yet?

Comment: I thought a circle of zero radius is not defined as a circle. it is a point... similarly a circle of infinite radius is not a circle. it is a straight line. so a line segment of 0 length is a point not a line segment. controversial topic. i havent looked into the formal defintion. 

Y is not in B because the question says a line segment joining two distinct points in A... 

anyways thanks for the answer...

Comment: Giving it a second thought, I see now why $Y$ must be excluded. If all points of $S_1$ are connected to $Y$ of $S_2$, now one gets more midpoints in $S_1$ also satisfying our prescribed rule; there arises ambiguity. Similarly there will be midpoints in $S_2$. Excluding $Y$ eliminates any such ambiguity.

Comment: @Sid In Cartesian plane, your definitions are correct. But then definition of circle is extended to include zero and infinite radii in modern Geometry to develop new analytic tools. If you read about radical axis, you'll come across circle of zero radius there.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that transformation $A\mapsto B$ from bigger circle which has radius $2\sqrt{10}$: $$XY  = \sqrt{4^2 +12^2} = 4\sqrt{10}$$ and center at $O(0,1)$ to smaller circle with radius $\sqrt{10}$ and center at $O'(3,-8)$ is homothety with center at $Y$ and dilatation factor $-1/2$. So, for all $A$ we have $${BY\over YA} = {1\over 2}\implies {AB\over YA} ={3\over 2}$$

Then $${YM \over YA} = 1- {AM\over YA}  = 1-{AB\over 2YA}  = {1\over 4} $$

[image]

So $M$ is actually a picture of $A$ under homothety at $Y$ with dilatation factor $1/4$, so $M$ descibes a circle with radius $r=\sqrt{10}/2$ and center at $({1\over 2},-{7\over 2})$.

Comment: Too many fancy words, though it may be correct... Need an answer for level of a 12th grade students.

Comment: Well, that is a solution for 10th grade students.

Comment: @Aqua did you mean that the bigger circle $C_1$ has radius $2\sqrt{10}$?

Comment: OK just one qstn. pls point out the line segment causing Y to be part of the locus B. bcuz i cant seem to find such a line segment that joins two distinct points in A *and* whose midpoint is Y. pls describe such a line segment. thank you.

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes, of course, thanks.